# What is up with Twitter Developer documentation?

Tags: twitter, twitter-api-v2

The Twitter Developer Portal starting May'23 now only shows V2 Apis under "Products", (as opposed to showing V1 as well).

[image]

And in March/April, they announced the new Access Level Tiers for Twitter API - Free Tier, Basic Tier at $100, Pro Tier at $5000 (recently) and a Custom Tier for enterprises. However the rate limits given in the Developer Portal for these Tiers does not match the documentation the Developer Portal's "learn more" link redirects to: https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/projects/overview - which talks about the old format with Essential Access, Elevated Access etc. with the old rate limits of 1M tweets etc.

So is it just that Twitter has not updated their Dev Documentation?

What further confuses me is that on my Twitter Developer Console, it says I can pull upto 1500 tweets per month on my free tier.

[image]

but then the documentation [here](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/getting-started/about-twitter-api#v2-access-level) says otherwise:

[image]

What is really being offered in the free tier? I know that I can pull tweets using the v2 stream apis - I have been successfully doing it so far - as the screenshot shows 400 pulled tweets. But for some reason, I get a 403 for all V2 stream apis now for Stream Apis.

So what really is the current situation? I need to decide when I must choose to upgrade to the next tier. Reaching out to Twitter Developers for clarification has been futile.